# Raphael on click change

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

The code loads image using JavaScript and Raphael successfully.

```
window.onload = function () {
    var src = document.getElementById("bee").src,
        angle = 0;
    document.getElementById("holder").innerHTML = "";
    var R = Raphael("holder", 640, 480);
    R.circle(320, 240, 200).attr({
        fill: "#000",
        "fill-opacity": .5,
        "stroke-width": 5
    });
    var img = R.image(src, 160, 120, 320, 240);
    var butt1 = R.set(),
        butt2 = R.set();
    butt1.push(R.circle(24.833, 26.917, 26.667).attr({
            stroke: "#ccc",
            fill: "#fff",
            "fill-opacity": .4,
            "stroke-width": 2
        }),
        R.path("M12.582,9.551C3.251,16.237,0.921,29.021,7.08,38.564l-2.36,1.689l4.893,2.262l4.893,2.262l-0.568-5.36l-0.567-5.359l-2.365,1.694c-4.657-7.375-2.83-17.185,4.352-22.33c7.451-5.338,17.817-3.625,23.156,3.824c5.337,7.449,3.625,17.813-3.821,23.152l2.857,3.988c9.617-6.893,11.827-20.277,4.935-29.896C35.591,4.87,22.204,2.658,12.582,9.551z").attr({
            stroke: "none",
            fill: "#000"
        }),
        R.circle(24.833, 26.917, 26.667).attr({
            fill: "#fff",
            opacity: 0
        }));
    butt2.push(R.circle(24.833, 26.917, 26.667).attr({
            stroke: "#ccc",
            fill: "#fff",
            "fill-opacity": .4,
            "stroke-width": 2
        }),
        R.path("M37.566,9.551c9.331,6.686,11.661,19.471,5.502,29.014l2.36,1.689l-4.893,2.262l-4.893,2.262l0.568-5.36l0.567-5.359l2.365,1.694c4.657-7.375,2.83-17.185-4.352-22.33c-7.451-5.338-17.817-3.625-23.156,3.824C6.3,24.695,8.012,35.06,15.458,40.398l-2.857,3.988C2.983,37.494,0.773,24.109,7.666,14.49C14.558,4.87,27.944,2.658,37.566,9.551z").attr({
            stroke: "none",
            fill: "#000"
        }),
        R.circle(24.833, 26.917, 26.667).attr({
            fill: "#fff",
            opacity: 0
        }));
    butt1.translate(10, 181);
    butt2.translate(10, 245);
    butt1[2].click(function () {
        angle -= 90;
        img.stop().animate({
            transform: "r" + angle
        }, 1000, "<>");
    }).mouseover(function () {
        butt1[1].animate({
            fill: "#fc0"
        }, 300);
    }).mouseout(function () {
        butt1[1].stop().attr({
            fill: "#000"
        });
    });
    butt2[2].click(function () {
        angle += 90;
        img.animate({
            transform: "r" + angle
        }, 1000, "<>");
    }).mouseover(function () {
        butt2[1].animate({
            fill: "#fc0"
        }, 300);
    }).mouseout(function () {
        butt2[1].stop().attr({
            fill: "#000"
        });
    });
    // setTimeout(function () {R.safari();});
};
```

But now the problem is I want to load another image when there is an `onclick` event. The `onclick` event capture is something like below. I can see an alert but the method fails to load the image. Could you suggest what could be incorrect here?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#image').click(function(event) {
        "use strict";

        event.preventDefault();
        alert("clicked");


            var src = document.getElementById("bee").src,
                angle = 0;
            document.getElementById("holder").innerHTML = "";
            var R = Raphael("holder", 640, 480);
            R.circle(320, 240, 200).attr({fill: "#000", "fill-opacity": .5, "stroke-width": 5});
            var img = R.image("new_image_location.jsp", 160, 120, 320, 240);
            var butt1 = R.set(),
                butt2 = R.set();
            butt1.push(R.circle(24.833, 26.917, 26.667).attr({stroke: "#ccc", fill: "#fff", "fill-opacity": .4, "stroke-width": 2}),
                       R.path("M12.582,9.551C3.251,16.237,0.921,29.021,7.08,38.564l-2.36,1.689l4.893,2.262l4.893,2.262l-0.568-5.36l-0.567-5.359l-2.365,1.694c-4.657-7.375-2.83-17.185,4.352-22.33c7.451-5.338,17.817-3.625,23.156,3.824c5.337,7.449,3.625,17.813-3.821,23.152l2.857,3.988c9.617-6.893,11.827-20.277,4.935-29.896C35.591,4.87,22.204,2.658,12.582,9.551z").attr({stroke: "none", fill: "#000"}),
                       R.circle(24.833, 26.917, 26.667).attr({fill: "#fff", opacity: 0}));
            butt2.push(R.circle(24.833, 26.917, 26.667).attr({stroke: "#ccc", fill: "#fff", "fill-opacity": .4, "stroke-width": 2}),
                       R.path("M37.566,9.551c9.331,6.686,11.661,19.471,5.502,29.014l2.36,1.689l-4.893,2.262l-4.893,2.262l0.568-5.36l0.567-5.359l2.365,1.694c4.657-7.375,2.83-17.185-4.352-22.33c-7.451-5.338-17.817-3.625-23.156,3.824C6.3,24.695,8.012,35.06,15.458,40.398l-2.857,3.988C2.983,37.494,0.773,24.109,7.666,14.49C14.558,4.87,27.944,2.658,37.566,9.551z").attr({stroke: "none", fill: "#000"}),
                       R.circle(24.833, 26.917, 26.667).attr({fill: "#fff", opacity: 0}));
            butt1.translate(10, 181);
            butt2.translate(10, 245);
            butt1[2].click(function () {
                angle -= 90;
                img.stop().animate({transform: "r" + angle}, 1000, "<>");
            }).mouseover(function () {
                butt1[1].animate({fill: "#fc0"}, 300);
            }).mouseout(function () {
                butt1[1].stop().attr({fill: "#000"});
            });
            butt2[2].click(function () {
                angle += 90;
                img.animate({transform: "r" + angle}, 1000, "<>");
            }).mouseover(function () {
                butt2[1].animate({fill: "#fc0"}, 300);
            }).mouseout(function () {
                butt2[1].stop().attr({fill: "#000"});
            });
            // setTimeout(function () {R.safari();});
    }
 });
```

Comment: dont see problem with code...can you share code related to loading image??

Comment: What does the URL `new_image_location.jsp` return? Is it really an image? If I replace it with an existing png from imgur, then the code works (there was just a tiny "parenthesis problem" at the end).

Comment: It's a link to an image. I will try again and confirm with firebug. I fixed the parenthesis.